# Add a line break after each element is cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

```
$('.footnote').clone().appendTo('#allfootnotes').append('<br>');
```

I have a bunch of `.footnote` elements all through the page, at the bottom of the page I want to list all of the footnotes on the page. So each footnote will be cloned to `#allfootnotes`. I'm trying to place a line break after each `.footnote` in the `#allfootnotes` element, so they're not all jumbled together.

How would I apply the line break after each `.footnote` once it's been cloned to `#allfootnotes`?

And is this the best way to do it? In each `.footnote` there's 2 span tags, one for the title, and one for the footnote content(don't know if that matters or not).

Comment: CSS is the preferred way to alter layout issues (e.g. "jumbled together").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you could use CSS to do this

```
#allfootnotes .footnote {
  margin-bottom: 10px;      
}
```

Depending on your situation you may need to make .footnote a block level element with `display: block;`

Answer (score 3):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/afiyun/edit#javascript,html,live)**

```
$('.footnote').clone().appendTo('#allfootnotes').after('<br>');
```

If you use XHTML than it should be `<br />`

Answer (score 0):

```
var allFootNotes = $('#allfootnotes');
$('.footnote').each(function(){
     $(this).clone().add('<br/>').appendTo(allFootNotes);
});
```

If there are as many foot notes as you say cacheing your `$('#allfootnotes')` will decrease load on the browser.

Hope this helps

Comment: Just a tip: If you are already invoking *class* elements, than you don't need the `.each()` function method. And there's also no need to cache an `ID` element especially if used/called only once.

Comment: Um appendTo() would be invoked on every each call and he eluded that there are many ".footnotes". Whether you declare the each or have jQuery pipe it internally cacheing would be your friend.

Comment: Good rule of thumb is any time your going to evoke the selector engine more than once it would be beneficial to cache your selections.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.footnote').each(function() {
    $(this).clone().add('<br/>').appendTo('#allfootnotes');
});
```

**EDIT** Please see roXon's answer. It's way cleaner than iterating over footnotes yourself.

Comment: Just a tip: If you're already invoking `class` elements, than you don't actually need the `.each()` method.

Comment: @roXon Thanks. Never stumbled upon `.after` until now, though.